Exploring the Application of a Trimodal State Formula in Balancing Systems
I’ve been exploring a formula related to balancing states in dynamic systems, and I’d love to hear thoughts or insights on its interpretation. The formula is as follows:
enter image description here
​
​
Context: This formula is intended to describe how a system transitions between three states: amplification (+1), equilibrium (0), and absorption (-1), based on the net force

net
F
net
​
acting on it. The threshold

threshold
F
threshold
​
defines the boundary for these transitions.
What I’m Curious About:
Does this formula resemble any principles or models in mathematics or physics you’ve encountered before?
How might such a formula be interpreted in different contexts, such as physical systems, economics, or even abstract mathematical structures?
What kind of generalizations or additional constraints could make this more universally applicable?
What I’ve Done So Far: I’ve considered its application in simple physical systems, like balancing forces on a particle, but I suspect it might have broader implications. I’m particularly interested in how this trimodal behavior might map onto more complex or abstract systems.
Acknowledgment: I’m not looking for anyone to solve this for me, but rather to provide guidance or share insights that could help deepen my understanding of how such a framework could be applied or expanded.
Thanks in advance for your thoughts and expertise! 
I have posted the formula as an image to avoid any formating issues.
